# How To Get Child Elements Of tag 'li' In The 'ul' In javascript

Tags: javascript, html

When getting the list elements in ul, we use get element by class name or tag and are returned in an array

```
var targetImages = document.getElementById("image-list-view").getElementsByTagName("img");
```

I need to get the element image in this list and i seem to be stack

```
<ul id="image-list-view">
    <li>
        <a href="#"  data-gallery>
            <img src="images/pic1.jpg"/>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"  data-gallery>
            <img src="images/pic2.jpg"/>
        </a>
    </li> 
</ul>
```

***EDIT***

Sorry i didnt explain the problem with the code.
[image: console chrome]

the code works fine when the site starts but `targetImages` can no longer be accessed later or referenced ie (images cannot be accessed);

Comment: *I need to get the element image in this list* Which one is that?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll  will allow you to write the CSS selector you want.

Comment: What's the problem? Looks fine to me, though you could simplify your DOM query with `document.querySelectorAll('#image-list-view img')`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts please see my edit. I cannot access the variable after the app is already running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the function `querySelectorAll` along with this selector `ul#image-list-view li img`.

> This approach allows you to get the image elements straightforward and avoid a second function execution. Further, this approach doesn't return `null` value if the element with id `image-list-view` doesn't exist.

```js
var targetImages = document.querySelectorAll("ul#image-list-view li img");
console.log("Count of images: " + targetImages.length);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }

ul {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<ul id="image-list-view">
  <li>
    <a href="#" data-gallery>
      <img src="images/pic1.jpg" />
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" data-gallery>
      <img src="images/pic2.jpg" />
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

## Resource

- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

  > Returns a list of the elements within the document (using depth-first pre-order traversal of the document's nodes) that match the specified group of selectors. The object returned is a NodeList.

Comment: awesome. the target images are now accessible at any time +1

Answer (score 3):

Your code works, you just need to loop thru the results and do something with the images.

[`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) returns an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), which is almost like an array. You can loop thru it the same way.

```js
var targetImages = document.getElementById("image-list-view").getElementsByTagName("img");

for (var i = 0; i < targetImages.length; i++) {
  console.log(targetImages[i]);
}
```

```html
I need to get the element image in this list and i seem to be stack

<ul id="image-list-view">
  <li>
    <a href="#" data-gallery>
      <img src="images/pic1.jpg" />
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" data-gallery>
      <img src="images/pic2.jpg" />
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your answer is the one that i have. The code works well during website loading but the method cannot be used to access the *target images* once the app is running

Comment: @Lucem of course you can use this while the app is running. that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: please check the updated question i posted the image of the console. The variable is undefined after the website is done loading. thanks for your answer. I really appreciate.

Comment: @Lucem if you're using a variable that is created earlier in the script there are many reasons that variable might not be available, but if you were able to use it with querySelector then this method will work too. in any case, I'm glad you got it working.

Comment: sure mate, i thought i was doing it wrong until you posted your answer. I dont know why i cant access it too. query selector did solve